# How to put code into a function

Tags: javascript

I have this code for an `textarea` field:

```
$('#m1').keyup(function () {
    var max = 300;
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    var $textarea = $(this);

    if (len >= max) {
        $('#charNum1').text('...you have reached the limit of 300')
    .css ({
      "color":"#ff3b3b",
      "background-color":"#ffffb1",
      "width":"190px"
    });

    //alert($this.text());
    $textarea.val($textarea.val().slice(0, max));
    } else {
        var char = max - len;
        $('#charNum1').text(char + ' characters left')
          .css({
      "color":"green",
      "background-color":"white"
    });

    }
});
```

The thing is that I have 5 such areas:

```
#m1 #m2 #m3 #m4 #m5
#charNum1 #charNum2 #charNum3 #charNum4 #charNum5
```

And of course I want to avoid copying the code 5 (actually 4...) times.

When the load pages, it retrieves values from a table and populates `#m1...#m5` and it already counts the characters.

Comment: There is likely a **MUCH** simpler way of doing this by adjusting your markup a bit.

Comment: Just apply the concept of KISS. Keep It Simple S

Comment: If you could provide the HTML structure as well, you will likely get a better answer.

Comment: Do it on a class name instead of an ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming one ID is always a match of the other:

```
$('#m1,#m2,#m3,#m4,#m5').keypress(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $count = $('#charNum' + this.id.match(/(\d+)$/)[0]);
    // $this = m#
    // $count = charNum# that's associated with the m#
});
```

Of course you could always bind the association using a `data-*` attribute:

```
<textarea id="m1" data-count="charNum1"></textarea>
<span id="charNum1">300 characters left</span>
```

Which makes `$count == $('#' + $(this).data('count'))` instead.

Assuming I understand the question correctly...

Answer (score 4):

To make that function work on your `#m*` elements, just select multiple elements:

```
$('#m1, #m2, #m3').keyup(...
```

For the rest of the code I would have put *data attributes* on the `#m*` elements saying which `#charNum*` element should it address. You can do it with more *arguments* or using *substrings* etc., but I believe it's more **generic** this way.

For instance:

```
<textarea id="m1" data-counter="#charNum1"></textarea>
```

Than inside the keyup handler, instead of using `$('#charNum1')`, use:

```
// $('#charNum1')
$($textarea.data("counter"))
```